# Can't enable privileges in current process token

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to enable the SeDebugPrivilege for my process by using the `AdjustTokenPrivileges` function, it succeeds but no privileges are enabled and the last error code is ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED.

I read the documentation of the function and looked for examples both here and on other sites to understand if I was doing something wrong but I couldn't find any problems.

I checked if my user account has this privilege and it does (the Administrator group does have it and the account is part of the group).

The application is running elevated.

This is the method that I use to enable the privilege:

```
    public static bool EnableRequiredPrivilegesForCurrentProcess()
    {
        IntPtr TokenHandle = GetCurrentProcessTokenForWriting();
        Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] PrivilegesLUIDs = new Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
        if (Win32SecurityFunctions.LookupPrivilegeValue(null, Win32Constants.SE_DEBUG_NAME, out Win32Structures.LUID DebugPrivilegeLUID))
        {
            Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Attribute = new()
            {
                Luid = DebugPrivilegeLUID,
                Attributes = (uint)Win32Enumerations.PrivilegeLUIDAttributes.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED //0x00000002
            };
            PrivilegesLUIDs[0] = Attribute;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        int StructureSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES));
        IntPtr LuidAttributesArrayPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(StructureSize * PrivilegesLUIDs.Length);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(PrivilegesLUIDs[0], LuidAttributesArrayPointer, false);
        Win32Structures.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewPrivileges = new()
        {
            PrivilegeCount = 1,
            Privileges = LuidAttributesArrayPointer
        };
        if (Win32TokenFunctions.AdjustTokenPrivileges(TokenHandle, false, ref NewPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out _))
        {
            Marshal.DestroyStructure(LuidAttributesArrayPointer, typeof(Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(LuidAttributesArrayPointer);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Win32OtherFunctions.CloseHandle(TokenHandle);
            Marshal.DestroyStructure(LuidAttributesArrayPointer, typeof(Win32Structures.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(LuidAttributesArrayPointer);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the `GetCurrentProcessTokenForWriting()` method referenced in the first line:

```
    private static IntPtr GetCurrentProcessTokenForWriting()
    {
        if (Win32TokenFunctions.OpenProcessToken(Win32OtherFunctions.GetCurrentProcess(), Win32Enumerations.TokenAccessRights.TOKEN_WRITE, out IntPtr TokenHandle))
        {
            return TokenHandle;
        }
        else
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
```

My application gathers a wide array of info from all processes in the system by calling various functions which require different access rights on the process handle, I require the SeDebugPrivilege to be able to open an handle to a process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS access right (if possible).

Comment: `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` mean that your token have not `SeDebugPrivilege` and it can not be enabled. as side note `CloseHandle(TokenHandle);` must be always called

Comment: I knew what the error meant, in order to be sure of it I used Process Hacker that I have on my computer to see the list of privileges held by the access token of the process, SeDebugPrivilege was in the list (it was disabled but it was there), that's why I don't understand the reason of this error code.

Comment: I also checked using Process Explorer and the privilege was in the list.

Comment: error `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` can be only in case some LUID in `NewState` not exist in token and other parameters valid. or you have not in token `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` (you can hardcode this luid instead call `LookupPrivilegeValue`) or you pass another luid. i can not check *c#* code.